# Passing construction parameters to redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware

I was curious if there is a way to pass a parameter to a middleware without retrieving it from the state. What I want to do is to pass a generic function that we are using that determines if the user is authenticated or not. So rather than retreiving the authentication information from the state which will be code duplication, I want to pass `isAuthenticated` function to the middleware.

I don't think this is implemented natively in `applyMiddleware` framework but maybe someone has a work around for this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the right way to do this turned out to be a wrapper function that will wrap the actual middleware function

```
export const middlewareFunction = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    do some stuff with something...
}
```

If this is your actual middleware function, than you should be applying the middleware as

```
applyMiddleware(middlewareFunction);
```

What you should be doing to pass a parameter is to implement a function like

```
export const middlewareWrapper = (args) => {
    do some stuff with your args 
    return (state) => (next) => (action) => {
        do more stuff with your args and actions
    }
}
```

With this syntax you can apply the middleware as :

```
applyMiddleware(middlewareWrapper(args));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since actions passed to middleware don't have to be pure, you can pass a function as part of the action. Since the middleware has an access to the store, and using `store.getState()` to the state, we can apply the method to the state, and get a computed result.

In the api middleware from the [real world example of redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js) you can see that the `endpoint` can be a function, and the actual endpoint can be computed from state (see the code between the asterisks comments):

```
export default store => next => action => {
  const callAPI = action[CALL_API]
  if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') {
    return next(action)
  }

  let { endpoint } = callAPI
  const { schema, types } = callAPI

 /***************************************************************************/    
  /** if the endpoint is a function compute the actual endpoint from state ***/
  if (typeof endpoint === 'function') {
    endpoint = endpoint(store.getState())
  }
  /***************************************************************************/

  if (typeof endpoint !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('Specify a string endpoint URL.')
  }
  if (!schema) {
    throw new Error('Specify one of the exported Schemas.')
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(types) || types.length !== 3) {
    throw new Error('Expected an array of three action types.')
  }
  if (!types.every(type => typeof type === 'string')) {
    throw new Error('Expected action types to be strings.')
  }

  function actionWith(data) {
    const finalAction = Object.assign({}, action, data)
    delete finalAction[CALL_API]
    return finalAction
  }

  const [ requestType, successType, failureType ] = types
  next(actionWith({ type: requestType }))

  return callApi(endpoint, schema).then(
    response => next(actionWith({
      response,
      type: successType
    })),
    error => next(actionWith({
      type: failureType,
      error: error.message || 'Something bad happened'
    }))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right approach is to curry again.

File where you use the middleware

```
import myMiddleWare from '/myMiddleWare.js'
import { applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

args = // whatever arguments you want    
applyMiddleware(myMiddleWare(args))
```

myMiddleWare.js

```
export default (args) => ({getState, dispatch}) => (next) => (action) => (
  // Use args do your hearts content
)
```